# How to set/get value in associative array in multidimensional (2D) array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I would like set/get value in associative array in 2D array in JavaScript. I used a following source code:

```js
var properties = {
  "isBold": false,
  "isItalic": false,
  "isUnderline": false
};

// Creation of 2D array, 6x6
var listOfProperties = new Array(6);
for (var i = 0; i < listOfProperties.length; i++) {
  listOfProperties[i] = new Array(6);
}

// Population of listOfProperties with properties
for (var row = 0; row < listOfProperties.length; row++) {
  for (var col = 0; col < listOfProperties.length; col++) {
    listOfProperties[row][col] = properties;
  }
}

var property = listOfProperties[2][2];
property.isBold = true; // I would like to populate property isBold
console.log("property > " + property.isBold);

var property = listOfProperties[0][0];
property.isBold = false;
console.log("property > " + property.isBold);

var property = listOfProperties[2][2];
console.log("property > " + property.isBold);
```

I created 2D array which I populated with *properties* (associative array). Then I set a *true* for *isBold* in *listOfProperties[2][2]* and *false* for *isBold* in *listOfProperties[0][0]*.

But why *isBold* in *listOfProperties[2][2]* includes *false* instead *true*?

What I do wrong?

Comment: you need to set `property.isBold = true;` after line `var property = listOfProperties[2][2];`

Comment: Thank you aRvi I wasn't 100% concentrated ...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this question I didn't notice I forgot set a true for listOfProperties[2][2]